# "Падает" сервер на Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

Столкнулся с такой проблемой -  сервер "падает" периодически - не подключиться ни по SSH, ни по FTP, ни по HTTP
UFW отключен, следовательно - это не может быть из-за него
Соединение по VNC работает.
Что можно сделать для решения данной проблемы?

Comment: По VNC подключается к серверу или к какому-нибудь IPMI?

Comment: Вообще, вы нисколько не описали проблему. В таком виде вы можете решить её только самостоятельно..

Comment: @DiD, к серверу

Comment: @DiD я не понимаю, в каких логах может находиться сообщение об этой проблеме

Comment: В чем такая уверенность? По VNC подключается когда сервер выключен?

Comment: У меня сервер время от времени так же отваливался. Проблема была в плохо настроенном DHCP клиенте. Когда истекает DHCP Lease, тогда Ubuntu сбрасывает настройки маршрутизации. Соответственно, узел перестаёт высылать ответы на запросы.

Comment: Ну так у вас сеть падает, а причем тут тогда ssh, ftp, http и vnc?

Comment: смотрите логи. было подобное вследствие DOS атак на стандартные порты (у меня это был vnc порт 5900)

Comment: какое ПО отвечает за управление сетью у вас? netctl, connman или networkmanager? netplan?